# How to properly add a domain to Heroku

Tags: domain-name-system, heroku

I'm a software developer and I'm looking to buy a domain so I can host my current and future projects on. I've done research, but as I'm still not sure if I understand this correctly, I am asking here for help.

Let's say I have bought an example.com domain. As the DNS system is hierarchical, I also now own all the subdomains of example.com, like a.example.com, b.example.com and a.b.c.example.com. So, for every new project that I want to deploy I will be able to allocate a projectname.example.com domain.

To exercise this ownership, I'm being given access to the NS record of the .com domain registry through registrar, so i can set the DNS server responsible for resolving my domain. By default this is going to be the server that registrar has provided me with.

When I deploy an application to the cloud, I'll get a url, for example project1.heroku.com. To redirect traffic, I can just create a CNAME or ALIAS records from project1.example.com to project1.heroku.com

But according to the Heroku documentation, I need to add the domain to heroku itself and then crate a CNAME record to url which I will be given upon doing so. Why is that, and why wouldn't the normal url work? Or do I really don't understand something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common misconception. A `CNAME` doesn't perform HTTP *redirection* nor create an alias to the web server. It simply tells that the DNS `A` record can be found elsewhere.

The web server only gets the original hostname in the browser's address bar via the `Host` header. The web server doesn't have any connection with the DNS infrastructure i.e. it doesn't check any `CNAME` records at all. Therefore, the web server needs to be aware of the hostname (i.e. configured property) in order to serve the correct content (virtual host).

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'll analyze your answer and definitely accept it later

Comment: So to summarize, although upon creating an CNAME record from project1.example.com to project1.herokuapp.com, both these addresses resolve to same IP address, the host header has a diffrent value, and due to the fact that heroku is setup only to respond with my application when the header is project1.herokuapp.com, I need to add a domain in order for it to respond for project1.example.com too. Is this correct?

Comment: Affirmative! The HTTP would only have `Host: project1.example.com`

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time!